# Is it possible to merge raster base maps with a DTM?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, display

In ArcMap 10.1

I have two raster layer 1) a raster base map and 2) a DEM raster.

Is it possible to merge the two to create an attractive visual showing the background map and terrain?  i.e. in Global Mapper there is an option to multiply layers together.

I have tried putting the base map on top making it slightly transparent so the underlying DTM is visible underneath.  But the result is quite faint thereby missing off base map detail.

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a hillshade of the DEM and laying that, semi-transparent, over the basemap.  They will not be "merged" per se, but it should give the visual effect you are seeking.